# JS - modular programing

Tags: javascript, module

I want to set up a manager with a handler object that provides a specific function for each  request. Why is only syntax a) working in other sample code I saw syntax b)

a)

```
 my.manager.requesthandler.create();
```

.

b)

```
my.manager.requesthandler [create]();
```

.

// my manager-modul

```
(function(){

my.manager = (function(){


    var requesthandler = {


        create: function () {

            //do something
        }

    };

    return {

        requesthandler : requesthandler 
    };

})();

})();
```

Comment: if `my.manager.requesthandler.create();` works then b should be `my.manager.requesthandler["create"]();`

Comment: @user1651640 Thank You so much, You are totally right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`my.manager.requesthandler.create`

is equivalent to

`my.manager.requesthandler["create"]`

(notice the quotation marks)

what you wrote as b

`my.manager.requesthandler[create]`

means looking up a variable named `create` and getting

`my.manager.requesthandler["whatever string create's value is"]`